# Can a chrome extension store an X.509 Certificate in local storage?

Tags: google-chrome-extension, certificate, local-storage, x509certificate

I want to write a chrome extension that could receive an X.509 certificate from a server and store it securely in chrome's local storage.
Is this possible using chrome extensions API?
Is my only way to go using NPAPI?